# TransactionSynchronizationFactory in combination with JmsTransactionManager not working

Tags: spring-integration

I have a case where I read a file, convert the content to a String. Then split the string into multiple payloads and send those payloads individually to a Queue. I want to use a JmsTransactionManager so that all messages are send or none at all.

When the TX is successful I want to move the file to an Archive folder, otherwise move it to a Failed folder. I have read that I can use transactionSynchronizationFactory to accomplish this. But in combination with a JmsTransactionManager the file is not moved. If I use a PseudoTransactionManager, then the file is moved, but I loose my JmsTransaction.

I have made a simplified version to reproduce the issue. (The content of the file in this case is a simple comma separated list of values.)

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileInboundAdaptor() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(s -> s.file(new File(INBOUND_PATH))
                            .patternFilter("*.txt"),
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)
                            .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory())
                            .transactional(new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory))

                    )

            )

            .transform(Transformers.fileToString())
            .split(s -> s.applySequence(false).get().getT2().setDelimiters(","))
            .handle((GenericHandler<String>) (payload, headers) -> {
                jmsTemplate.send("SOME_QUEUE", (Session session) -> session.createTextMessage(payload));
                return payload;
            })
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("fileReadingResultChannel"))
            .get();
}
```

The transactionSynchronizationFactory looks like this:

```
@Bean
public TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor syncProcessor
            = new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
    syncProcessor.setBeanFactory(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
    syncProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(parser.parseExpression(
            "payload.renameTo(new java.io.File('test/archive' " +
                    " + T(java.io.File).separator + 'ARCHIVE-' + payload.name))"));
    syncProcessor.setAfterRollbackExpression(parser.parseExpression(
            "payload.renameTo(new java.io.File('test/fail' " +
                    " + T(java.io.File).separator + 'FAILED-' + payload.name))"));
    return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(syncProcessor);
}
```

So my question is: does TransactionSynchronizationFactory only work with PseudoTransactionManager or is supposed to work with JmsTransactionManager aswell?

**Solution**

I needed to set the transactionSynchronization on the JmsTransaction. Something like this:

```
public JmsTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
    jmsTransactionManager.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
    return jmsTransactionManager;
}
```

Comment: Try to make that `JmsTransactionManager` as a `@Bean`. It isn't registered with the ApplicationContext from that `.transactional()` option

Comment: This was not the problem. I added the solution in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think your issue is here:

```
/**
 * Create a new JmsTransactionManager for bean-style usage.
 * <p>Note: The ConnectionFactory has to be set before using the instance.
 * This constructor can be used to prepare a JmsTemplate via a BeanFactory,
 * typically setting the ConnectionFactory via setConnectionFactory.
 * <p>Turns off transaction synchronization by default, as this manager might
 * be used alongside a datastore-based Spring transaction manager like
 * DataSourceTransactionManager, which has stronger needs for synchronization.
 * Only one manager is allowed to drive synchronization at any point of time.
 * @see #setConnectionFactory
 * @see #setTransactionSynchronization
 */
public JmsTransactionManager() {
    setTransactionSynchronization(SYNCHRONIZATION_NEVER);
}
```

So, you have to manually switch on it into `setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ALWAYS);`

Comment: Yes now it works! I did not know the synchronization was off by default. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Neither do I. JavaDocs are our friends :)